# what is the answer of this Homogeneous equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Please help me.

> Question:what is the answer of this Homogeneous equation?
>
> $m^4(m+1)^3(m+5)(m^2+1)^2$

My guess is:

$m^4: m=0 \Rightarrow y_1=e^0 , y_2=xe^0 , y_3=x^2e^0 , y^4=x^3e^0$

$(m+1)^3: m=-1 \Rightarrow y_5=e^-x , y_6=xe^-x , y_7=x^2e^-x $

$(m+5): m=-5 \Rightarrow y_8=e^-5x$

$(m^2+1)^2: m^2+1=0 \rightarrow m=+i , m=-i \Rightarrow $

$y_9=sin x , y_10=cos x , y_{11}=x sin x , y_{12}=x cos x  $

$y_c=c_1e^0+c_2xe^0+c_3x^2e^0+c_4x^3e^0+c_5e^{-x}+c_6xe^{-x}+c_7x^2e^{-x}+c_8e^{-5x}+c_9sin x + c_{10}cos x + c_{11}x sin x + c_{12} x cos x$

Now

is this true?

Comment: What is the equation?

Comment: m^4(m+1)^3(m+5)(m^2+1)^2

Comment: If you are trying to find the kernel of the differential operator $D^4(D+1)^3(D+5)(D^2+1)^2$ then your answer seems to be correct.

Comment: @Abel: yes,Precisely.Thank you for your attention. :)

Comment: @BabakS. :Yes, I agree with you. Thank you for your presence

Comment: @BabakS.:bale.man ba shoma movafegham hata khodam ham sar nemizanam va faghat baraye in k bedoonam dae goft besazam va agar na aslan nemifahmamesh.barha beheshoon ghoftan.emrozam ghoftam k: bebin harfe mano goosh nadadi! goft nemikhad diactivate kone.faghat mitarse az tarafe oon be familesh pm bede.

Comment: @Babak S.:e-mail va pass ro be man dade.naran?khodam be fata etela bedam?(akhe man khodam hamyar police fata hastam)

Comment: $\;\;\ddot\smile +\;$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A repost of my comment to formally close this question:

If you are trying to find the kernel of the differential operator $$P(D)=D^4(D+1)^3(D+5)(D^2+1)^2$$ then your answer seems to be correct.

Comment: +Thanks very much for your answer ;)